# Plupload simultaneous uploading

Tags: javascript, plupload

I'm using plupload with Asp.Net through a generic handler. I have a fully custom interface so I am just binding javascript. I have coded it to start automatically, but the files upload one at a time. Is there a way to make the files upload in parallel? I assign unique filenames to everything so that isn't a concern.

```
    var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes: 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
        browse_button: 'select-from-folder',
        container: 'uploader',
        drop_element: 'uploader-drop-element',
        max_file_size: '2000mb',
        chunk_size: '1mb',
        unique_names: true,
        url: '/myuploader.ashx?globalId=' + globalId,
        flash_swf_url: '/scripts/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',
        silverlight_xap_url: '/scripts/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap',
        filters: [
            {
                title: "Application Supported",
                extensions: "jpg,gif,png,pdf,mp4,flv,avi,wmv"
            }
        ]
    });

    uploader.init();


    uploader.bind('Init', function (up, params) { 
        // removed for brevity
    });

    uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function (up, files) {
        for (var i in files) {
            // removed for brevity
        }

        uploader.start(); // auto-start the uploader
    });

    uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function (up, file) {
        // removed for brevity
    });

    uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file, resp) {
        if (uploader.total.uploaded >= uploader.files.length) {
            // removed for brevity
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading through the documentation, it doesn't look to me like parallel uploads are currently supported, although you could probably modify the [source code](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/src/plupload.js) to do this with some [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers).

The actual uploads occur in the `uploadNext()` function ([line 897](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/js/plupload.dev.js#L897)).

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear, but you are indeed correct! Thanks MrT!

Comment: As a side note, I think uploadify (http://www.uploadify.com/) supports this (it seems to anyways), if its that important. You're welcome Kruzy.

Comment: I have tried a bunch. I need file filtering, chunked uploading, and full html customization (for our crazy designers). I don't think uploadify does chunked uploading.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a new plupload instance for each parallel transfer you need to make. Wrapping these instances in a class similar to pluploads and binding the settings and events in proper way is essential. Also you need to implement a custom `handleFilesAdded` method that distributes the new files to cluster.

There is a project that create cluster of plupload instances and make parallel posts. You can check at: https://github.com/bennadel/Plupload-Cluster